# How to create a static hello world program in C using yocto - zynq?

Tags: yocto

I am trying to create a simple hello world program in C using yocto.
Here are my steps. Basically, I want to program this elf using JTAG to my Zedboard.

```
source /opt/poky/2.5.3/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi 

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("Hello S..welcome to JTAG World\r\n");
  return 0;
}




  #$CC test.c --static -o test.elf

/opt/poky/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Does is work if you drop the `--static`?

Comment: it works if I drop static